# Bash, how to delete unique filenames?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

In a folder there are `.mp4` files; and `.txt` files which containing text info about `.mp4` files, with same filename. But there are some `.mp4` files without text file. I want to delete only these (unique) `.mp4` files, is there an easy way to do it in `Bash` (Ubuntu14.04) ?

Example:

```
001.mp4
001.txt
002.mp4
002.txt
003.mp4
004.mp4
004.txt
```

I want to delete only `003.mp4` from folder.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: does the folder only contain txt and mp4 files?

Comment: Hello, yes, .mp4 and .txt files are the only filetypes in the folder. There are thousands of them.

Comment: What should be done if there is only .txt file? Do you want to delete files that are not coupled or just the .mp4 files that don't have .txt files?

Comment: I want to delete .mp4 files that dont have .txt pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echo to see first which files will be deleted

```
for file in *.mp4 ; do [[ -f ${file%.mp4}.txt ]] || echo "file not found ${file%.mp4}.txt"; done
```

Remove files

```
for file in *.mp4 ; do [[ -f ${file%.mp4}.txt ]] || /usr/bin/rm "${file}"; done
```

Or depending where command rm is located and to avoid using alias

```
for file in *.mp4 ; do [[ -f ${file%.mp4}.txt ]] || \rm "${file}"; done
```

Comment: It appears there is no rm file in /usr/bin;


  remover.sh: line 1: /usr/bin/rm: No such file or directory

Ok It worked well after changing "/usr/bin/rm" to just  "rm", thank you very much!

Comment: you can also just use rm or `\rm`to avoid using alias, but `type rm` or `which rm` will give you the command used

Answer (score 0):

A list based approach.

This generates a list of all `txt` files having the extension `.txt` striped off:

```
basename -as.txt *.txt
```

The same for the `mp4` files:

```
basename -as.mp4 *.mp4
```

`grep` can be used to subtract two lists.  This is the list of `mp4` files, without the `txt` files:

```
basename -as.mp4 *.mp4 | grep -vf <(basename -as.txt *.txt)
```

And `xargs` can be used to execute commands on lists:

```
basename -as.mp4 *.mp4 |
grep -vf <(basename -as.txt *.txt) |
xargs -i rm {}.mp4
```